# Google maps переопределение оформления

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api, google-maps

Доброго времени суток. Возник следующий вопрос:

**Имеется:** На сайте имеется блок с google maps. Он настроен так, что отображает аватар пользователя, если он зашел в Google+. Изображение круглое с диаметром в 32рх (как на примере: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?hl=ru).

**Должно быть:** Изображение квадратное с размером 60х60рх и с большим отступом от правого края.

Пробовал различными способами через jquery влезть в iframe, но судя по всему этого сделать нельзя по соглашению безопасности.
За ранее спасибо.

Comment: судя по всему никак. Пробовал получить доступ к блоку аватарки: $('iframe').contents().find('div.profile-photo img')
получил ошибку: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://developers.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: смотрите в сторону API к картам, там можете как угодно оформить

Comment: Алексей Стародубцев - вот и я такое сообщение получал:(
а в API к сожалению я ничего не нашел(..оригинальные кнопки сделал и все остальное..привязав к событиям API, а вот как переопределить изображение не знаю(

Comment: да в том то и дело что не могу в API найти то что надо(